# Video is not uploading on server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, upload, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to upload video on PHP server but it's not uploading.My code for image uploading is working fine but when I am trying to upload video it's sending me blank response.I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code.Please help me to resolve this issue.I didn't find any answer for this issue.

```
- (void)uploadVideo
{
  NSData *imageData = videoData;
  NSLog(@"imageData = %@",videoData);

  NSString *urlString = @"MyURL";
  NSLog(@"url=== %@", urlString);

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

  request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
  NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
  [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

  /*  body of the post */

  NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"any_media\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  [request setHTTPBody:body];

  NSURLResponse *response;
  NSError *error =nil;

  NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSLog(@"result from webservice:::--> %@", returnString);


  NSDictionary *parsingResultLogin = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:nil];
  NSLog(@"parsingResultLogin = %@",parsingResultLogin);
}
```

Comment: it would be a way better to see web server response details. such as http status code. the best way of tracing the problem in this situation is to use some traffic sniffer tool and see what exactly the app is sending in request and what does the server respond

Answer (score 0):

Add Content Length to the request as well.

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

And also make sure that `imageData != nil;`

Comment: I checked everything. I am testing with small video. In a body contents are there but it is not uploading.

Comment: I added your code and test it but it is also not working.. :(

Comment: I tested it is on Device but still I am getting returnData & returnString empty/Null. Device is opening .mov video file from gallery.

Comment: I have a clue that your Video is nil. Can you check imageData is not nil

Comment: I already checked , Image data is not nil and body is also having some contents.

Comment: Are you sure filename NSString has a value of something like "abcd.mov" & are you accepting mov file type from your server as well?

Comment: But when i am trying .mp4 from simulator at that time also it is  behaving same..